# C# dataset and Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5, crystal-reports

I am trying to use Crystal Reports on project I've been working on. I don't have too much experience with Crystal Reports but from what I was able to search on the web, I've done this chunk of code so far:

The markup:

```
 <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crViewerReports" Visible="true"  runat="server" 
            AutoDataBind="true" ReportSourceID="crs" />
       <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="crs" runat="server" >
           <Report FileName="MyReport.rpt">
           </Report>
       </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

Code:

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = util.getReportDataSet(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5), DateTime.Now, 100,4, null);
```

The Crystal Reports file is from other application and is working properly I just need to fetch the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The next step would be [assigning the data source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of your report to the dataset you just loaded:

```
crs.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(ds);
```

If you have parameters, you would also need to [set them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. as I can see from the field explorer I don't have parameters but I have Database Fields. What should I do with them? Thx a lot

Comment: If you don't have parameters then you don't need to do anything special, just setting the data source should be enough.

Comment: Everything goes well and at the end I am getting blank page although the dataset has data. Do you have idea why that can happen.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is aspx :

```
 <updatepanel id="up" updatemode="alwayz"> 
<ContentTemplate>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crvReportParameter" runat="server" Visible="false" EnableParameterPrompt="false"
                ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="true" ToolPanelView="None" AutoDataBind="true"
                HasCrystalLogo="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="false" />
</ContentTemplate>
</updatepanel>
```

This is CS File :

```
ds = util.getReportDataSet(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5), DateTime.Now, 100,4, null);
                            rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(""MyReport.rpt""));

        rptDoc.SetDataSource(dsData.Tables[0]);
     crvReportParameter.ReportSource = rptDoc;
                crvReportParameter.DataBind();
```